# How to create a web deployment package with only the Release folder in the zip

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been searching 2 hours for a solution that could help me create a web deployment package that only include the folders : obj\Release\Package.

At the moment, I'm following this guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx

And it creates a .zip with 13 folders. Something like that:
webApp.zip\Content\C_C\ProjectsFolder\companyName\ProjectsName\trunk\SolutionName\VisualStudioProjectName\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp

Is there a way to include only the "\Release\Package\PackageTmp" folders?

Comment: this should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same issue

Comment: @Nerlijma No, I had to edit the .zip file produced manually to keep only the desired folders.